# Side effects with BehaviorSubject and concatMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular11, concatmap

This is my first time experimenting with BehaviorSubject, async pipes and concatMap so I'm facing some problems updating data in my DOM.

I have:

```
private profilesStore = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
profiles$ = this.profilesStore.asObservable();

  getUserProfiles(): Observable<Profile[]> {
    const headers = this.authService.getHeaders();
    return this.http.get<any>(`${API_URL}/profile`, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => throwError(err)),
        tap(res => this.profilesStore.next(res)),
        shareReplay()
      );
  }
```

and then

```
addProduct(profileId: any) {
    const headers = this.authService.getHeaders();
    return this.http.post<any>(`${apiUrl}/products/${profileId}`, {}, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => throwError(err)),
        concatMap(() => this.profileService.profiles$),
        map(profiles => {
          const selectedProfile = profiles.findIndex(profile => profile.id === profileId);
            profiles[selectedProfile].canEdit = true;
            return profiles;
        })
      );
  }
```

This logic it's like a cart logic. I add a product to one of the profiles, so to avoid calling again the api (getUserProfiles) I modify profiles$ stream and add the property that I want (in this case canEdit) but the problem comes when I delete the product from the cart and recover data from getUserProfiles() I understand that as I use concatMap with profiles$ I get the side effect on addProduct() even if I haven't called that function, my question is...

Why does it continue performing

```
map(profiles => {
          const selectedProfile = profiles.findIndex(profile => profile.id === profileId);
          profiles[selectedProfile].canEdit = true;
            return profiles;
        })
```

with the old profileId that i passed in the past as parameters, even if i haven't called addProduct() function and how to avoid that?

Comment: Can you share a working example of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of observables as a water tap that, once you subscribe to it, the tap is never closed. Water will keep flowing, as long as, well there is water. Only when you unsubscribe it (or any other operators that ends it), then the tap will close.

So the moment you do a `addProfile()`, even just once, the observable of it is forever opened, and as long as there is emissions of data (water), that emission of data will still continues, even if you dont call the function `addProfile()` anymore -> and that, if you call the function two times, you actually have two subscriptions aka two water pipes and taps; which is something that most developers did not pay attention to.

So when you call `addProfile()` just for the first time, and since you never unsubscribe it, you actually switched to listening to `profiles$` thanks to

```
  concatMap(() => this.profileService.profiles$),
```

, your stream of data actually becomes listening to the changes of that BehaviourSubject, and that explains that even if you don't call `addProfile()` anymore, but because you update your `profiles$`, emissions still go through, and the flow of data will flow through the pipes, which, will then effectively perform the next pipe operator:

```
map(profiles => {
          const selectedProfile = profiles.findIndex(profile => profile.id === profileId);
          profiles[selectedProfile].canEdit = true;
            return profiles;
        })
```

Comment: I get it, it makes sense :D Actually I don't know why I didn't understand :D So actually what I was missing was to unsubscribe from addProduct(). 

Very valuable learning today.  Thanks!